# PHP MySQL article views count not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my blog, I want to count the articles views every time the page is loaded so I can make a chart of the top articles.

I'm using this code but something goes wrong.

If I put the first query in phpMyAdmin the query result is correct.

```
$readViewsCountSQL = "SELECT `view_count` FROM `andreaem`.`article` WHERE `article`.`slug` = '$articleSlug' LIMIT 1";
$readViewsCount = $DB_CON ->query($readViewsCountSQL); 
$readViewsCountResult = $readViewsCount->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

function updateVCount ($current) {
    $count = $current ++;
    return $count;
}
$addViewsCount = updateVCount($readViewsCountResult);
var_dump($addViewsCount); //This return the correct value
$updateViewsCount = "UPDATE `andreaem`.`article` SET  `view_count` =  '$addViewsCount' WHERE  `article`.`slug` = '$articleSlug'";
$DB_CON ->query($updateViewsCount);
```

In the mySQL logs the query was executed successfully but something goes wrong.

$DB_CON is the PDO connection and working in other queries

Comment: Please explain *something goes wrong*. What is not working? Just so you know, you don't need that `SELECT` query, you can do everything in just one query, `$updateViewsCount = "UPDATE andreaem.article SET view_count =  view_count+1 WHERE article.slug = '$articleSlug'";`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working! I didn't know it. If you post as an answer I'll make as replied.

Comment: Cheers! I've posted this as an answer. :-)

Comment: Your usage of the `++` is incorrect. It should have been https://eval.in/587844 or https://eval.in/587845.  Answer below is a better solution anyway though.

Comment: @chris85 You're right, was a typo! Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken straight from [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780025/php-mysql-article-views-count-not-working?noredirect=1#comment63027625_37780025),

You don't need *that* `SELECT` query, you can do everything in just one simple query,

```
$updateViewsCount = "UPDATE andreaem.article SET view_count = view_count+1 WHERE article.slug = '$articleSlug'";
```